# decoding breaks lines into characters in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a CSV file through samba share. My CSV file format

```
hello;world
1;2;
```

Python code

```
import urllib
from smb.SMBHandler import SMBHandler

PATH = 'smb://myusername:mypassword@192.168.1.200/myDir/'

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(SMBHandler)
fh = opener.open(PATH + 'myFileName')
data = fh.read().decode('utf-8')
print(data) // This prints the data right
csvfile = csv.reader(data, delimiter=';')
for myrow in csvfile:
    print(myrow) // This just prints ['h']. however it should print(hello;world)
    break
fh.close()
```

The problem is that after decoding to `utf-8`, the rows are not the actual lines in the file

Desired output of a row after reading the file: `hello;world`

Current output of a row after reading the file: `h`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv.reader` takes an iterable that returns *lines*. Strings, when iterated, yield *characters*. The fix is simple:

```
csvfile = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), delimiter=';')
```